# Azure : Error using certificate obtained from Key Vault in App Service

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

In my Azure App Service which runs a net472 web app, I access certificate from key vault as follows :

```
var certSecret = await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(kvName, secretName);
```

I then need to send the certificate to authenticate to an external service

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certSecret.Value));
```

This line throws an error

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get secret as below:

```
var certSecret = await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(vaultBaseUrl, secretName);
```

You could retrieve `certSecret.value` to check whether it has value then send it to `X509Certificate2` which specify the `X509KeyStorageFlags` storage flags.

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certSecret.value), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
```

Comment: The X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet did the trick